# error output when using commands proxied via WSL (asyncrun plugin)

Tags: external-command, microsoft-windows, plugin-asyncrun

I have wsl - ubuntu installed under Windows 10. Some ubuntu's commands are proxied to use in cmd by create `.bat` files and add them to `PATH` environment of windows10, pattern like following:

```
@echo off
bash.exe -c "ls %*"
```

Then in cmd `ls` work as expected, log in bash, run ls in current directory.

Problem is that, asyncrun throws an error output when I try to run, for i.e: `:AsyncRun ls`.

I am using gVim 8.1 1-42

EDIT: add error output:

```
|| E
|| r
|| r
|| o
|| r
|| :
|| 
|| 0
|| x
|| 8
|| 0
|| 0
|| 7
|| 0
|| 0
|| 0
|| 6
|| 
|| 
|| 
|| [Finished in 0 seconds with code -1]
```

Comment: Which error do you get? Does `:!ls` work?

Comment: @MartinTournoij: `:!ls` work perfect, that's why I wonder.